# str.startswith with a list of strings to test for

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to avoid using so many comparisons and simply use a list, but not sure how to use it with `str.startswith`:

```py
if link.lower().startswith("js/") or link.lower().startswith("catalog/") or link.lower().startswith("script/") or link.lower().startswith("scripts/") or link.lower().startswith("katalog/"):
    # then "do something"
```

What I would like it to be is:

```py
if link.lower().startswith() in ["js","catalog","script","scripts","katalog"]:
    # then "do something"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 610, accepted):

`str.startswith` allows you to supply a tuple of strings to test for:

```
if link.lower().startswith(("js", "catalog", "script", "katalog")):
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if string starts with the `prefix`, otherwise return `False`. **`prefix` can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.**

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> "abcde".startswith(("xyz", "abc"))
True
>>> prefixes = ["xyz", "abc"]
>>> "abcde".startswith(tuple(prefixes)) # You must use a tuple though
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 49):

You can also use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) like so:

```
if any(map(l.startswith, x)):
    pass # Do something
```

Or alternatively, using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
if any(l.startswith(s) for s in x)
    pass # Do something
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `next()` to iterate over the list of patterns.

```py
prefixes = ["xyz", "abc"]
my_string = "abcde"
next((True for s in prefixes if my_string.startswith(s)), False)   # True
```

One way where `next` could be useful is that it can return the prefix itself. Try:

```py
next((s for s in prefixes if my_string.startswith(s)), None)       # 'abc'
```