# What is the most efficient way to check if a word starts with certain prefixes?

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a hyphenated word starts with the prefixes in the following set. For example, "de-salt".

```
prefixes = {
    'de-', 'dis-', 'il-', 'im-', 'ir-', 'inter-',
    'mid-', 'mis-', 'non-', 'pre-', 'pro-', 're-',
    'semi-', 'sub-', 'tele-', 'trans-',
    'un-', 'e-'
}
```

Here is my code:

```
def prefix(word):
    match = re.match(r"[a-z]+-",word)
    if match:
        if match.group() in prefixes:
            return True
word = "e-mail"
print(prefix(word))
```

Comment: Do you want "telephone" to match?

Comment: This already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461847/str-startswith-with-a-list-of-strings-to-test-for) it's builtin to python

Comment: No. All words are hyphenated words.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: Was the question aimed at coding efficiency, or runtime efficiency? [However I would be surprised if there was a better answer than Jab's comment either way.]

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the prefixes first so that you can use the `bisect.bisect_left` method to find the closest word in the prefixes that's less than a given word in *O(log n)* time complexity:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
prefixes = sorted(prefixes)
def prefix(prefixes, word):
    i = bisect_left(prefixes, word)
    if i and word.startswith(prefixes[i - 1]):
        return prefixes[i - 1]
    raise ValueError("No prefix found for '%s'." % word)
```

so that:

```
print(prefix(prefixes, 'non-word'))
print(prefix(prefixes, 'tele-video'))
print(prefix(prefixes, 'e-mail'))
```

outputs:

```
non-
tele-
e-
```

Answer (score 2):

Bisect scales better than this. But the runtime does not look at comparing the prefixes. (Runtime = O(n log(n)) if you consider similar prefixes for the prefixes. But for the example it is a better solution.)

---

The most efficient way would be to
use only the first n characters (with n = max. length prefix) [optional: the state machine can do this for you too]
and to give each of those letters to a state machine.

That state machine would need to decide which prefixes are still possible to get.

```
E.g. to be tested: "prefix" with your list of prefixes
You start with "" -> everything is possible
You read the "p" -> {pro, pre} are possible prefixes now
You read the "r" -> still the same, both start with "pr"
You read the "e" -> pro is not possible and pre has been found.
```

---

It is possible to generate the state machine from a list of prefixes. But I won't go into that.

But it should result in a state and a transition table that depends on the current state and the next character read.

```
An example:
Let me add prof to your list of prefixes.

0:
p -> 1
? -> to be added, there are more prefixes

1:
r -> 2
? -> terminate, nothing found

2:
e -> terminate, found pre
o -> 3, found pro
? -> -1

3:
f -> terminate, found pro and prof
? -> terminate, found pro
```

How to read this:
    state:
    read character -> next state, found
    ? = anything else

Answer (score 1):

In your case I guess hashing would be efficient.

```
m=set()
for x in prefixes:
    m.add(x.split(‘-‘)[0])

return word.split(‘-‘)[0] in m
```