# How to make list of Next line of "line.startswith("Apr" or May or "Jun")"

Tags: python, list

The give input is text data:

```
file = open("ZZZ.txt").read().splitlines()
```

Sample result:

```
['Running from: ',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:29 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'WARNING: XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:29 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'WARNING: XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:29 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'INFO: XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:29 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'INFO: XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:33 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'WARNING: XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:33 PM YYYYYYYYY',
 'INFO: XXXXXXXXXXXXX]
```

I need to Extract the input data (`YYYYYYYYY`) and also have the info or warning (`XXXXXXXXXXXXX`).

I have tried to extract the input data by using `("Apr" or May or "Jun")`
and `line.startswith("INFO" or "WARNING")`

but I got different length key and values list,

```
key = []
value = []
for line in jenkins:
    if line.startswith("Apr" or May or "Jun"):
        line = line.rstrip()
        key.append(line)
else:
    if line.startswith("INFO" or "WARNING"):
        line = line.rstrip()
        value.append(line)
```

Comment: That really isn't how you use `startswith()`.

Comment: use regex; or `line.startswith("INFO") or line.startswith("WARNING")`

Comment: Much better dupe target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461847/str-startswith-with-a-list-of-strings-to-test-for

Comment: I guess it would be too easy to just get the dates from the odd lines & the data from the even lines (counting from 0).

Answer (score 1):

the or keyword does not work inside startswith function its valid syntax if you remove the or keyword its still valid syntax.

```
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('INFO') or line.startswith('WARNING'):
        keys.append(line.strip())
        values.append(lines[idx-1].strip())
```

Comment: Got this: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-bb2503ebca87> in <module>
     12         values.append(jenkins[idx-1].strip())
     13     else:
---> 14         print('date missing in line %s' %idx+1)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: i have removed the else part use it as is.

Comment: did the same, Thanks

Comment: Some times there  are N no of lines(Info or Warning msg) present between 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:33 PM YYYYYYYYY', data 'Apr 02, 2019 5:38:33 PM YYYYYYYYY', How to extract line between one input and other