# Delete sub-list from list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to remove the sub lists from a list in Python.

For example: The main list A contains

```
A=[ 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f' , 'g,h,i' , 'g,l,m' , 's,l,k' , 'd,k,l', 'a,g,d' ]
```

I need to remove the sub lists from A which begin with the items in the following list:

```
B = ['g','d']
```

so that Final List `A = [ 'a,b,c', 's,l,k' , 'a,g,d' ]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a sub list but an element of a flat list

Comment: Why isn't `'d,e,f'` removed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents),  [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8802860/4518341)

Comment: Even your output seems wrong. It should be `['a,b,c', 's,l,k', 'a,g,d']`. 2nd Element `'d,e,f'` should also be removed as start element `'d'` is in second list.

Comment: also [str.startswith with a list of strings to test for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20461847/4518341)

Comment: Question updated.. @wjandrea Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `list comprehension` and **`split(",")`**.

```
print([e for e in A if e.split(",")[0] not in B])
```

> Output

```
['a,b,c', 's,l,k', 'a,g,d']
```

Your output above for your approach is wrong. 
2nd Element `'d,e,f'` should also be removed as start element `'d'` is in second list.

Comment: @P_Ar, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension:

```
print([x for x in A if x[0] not in ['g', 'd']])
```

Comment: @CeliusStingher how does it not?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It does work I was having the wrong input. Changed to +1