# How can i get the full element name on a list

Tags: python, list, startswith

I have the following quick issue, hope you can help me.

I have a list `my_list` where there are like 900 elements and all the elements have the following format:

"###" + _ + "the name of the element"

Like this:
`['123_rop','456_tuy','789_wqw',......]`

How can I find the full element name with just the first 3 digits?

For example, I want to know the full name of the element that starts with "123".

The result must be:
`result="123_rop"`

The three first numbers of each element inside the list are never duplicated.

Comment: You can do a for-loop for this or maintain a dictionary where key is `"###"` and value is `"###" + _ + "the name of the element"` (something like `{'123':'123_rop', '456':'456_tuy'}`) to make the search faster.

Comment: You can use list comprehension & startswith, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461857/4985099

Comment: `[x for x in my_list if x.split("_")[0]=='123']`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
lst = ['123_rop','456_tuy','789_wqw',"123_hhj"]
[i for i in lst if "123" in i]
```

Comment: This will not give the desired output with an element like "hhk_123", because "123" is in "hhk_123", but "hhk_123" doesn´t start with "123".

Comment: Yes it is true. But we have this format "###" + _ + "the name of the element"

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_full_name(start_val)
    new_list = [elem for elem in my_list if elem.statswith(start_val)]
    return (new_list|'not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, somehow this works

```
def check_by_start(num):
    for i in list:
        if i.startswith(num):
            return i
print(check_by_start("887"))
```

but just with numbers, if I want to get an element that starts with letters it doesn't work