# How to use str.startswith with multiple strings?

Tags: python, discord

I've tried using the or function to input multiple words for the same output, but it only takes the first word as the input and not the rest. How do I solve this? Thanks!
For instance:

```
message.content.startswith("hi" or "hey")
```

only takes in "hi" as an input and not "hey".

I've tried adding the words in to a list and it doesn't work as well. I'm relatively new to coding so i'm sorry in advance if it's a stupid question

Comment: `startswith` is likely just the standard built-in string method.  And `startswith("hi" or "hey")` is equivalent to `startswith("hi")`. You'd need to manually check both by doing something like calling `startswith` twice.

Comment: Ahh, I was afraid that was the case. Now I have to manually input all the functions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Now I have to manually input all the functions.". You can just do `msg = message.content; msg.startswith("hi") or msg.startswith("hey")`. I introduced `msg` for the sake of brevity.

Comment: You can use the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here: `any(message.content.startswith(s) for s in ["hi", "hey"])`

Comment: @Alex why not turn that into an answer.

Comment: The `or` is not a function. It's an operator which returns the first truthy value according to what Python considers true. `"hi"` is always true, and that's why it is always returned. If you used `"" or "hey"`, for example, it would've returned hey. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false#39984051)

Comment: It's worth taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) t learn a bit more about testing multiple values against a single variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str.startswith with a list of strings to test for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461847/str-startswith-with-a-list-of-strings-to-test-for)

Answer (score 13):

You can code like this:

```
message.content.startswith(("hi", "hey"))
```

From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) for `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`, I've added emphasis:

> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return
> `False`. **prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for**. With
> optional start, test string beginning at that position. With optional
> end, stop comparing string at that position.